# How to update a variable first and then execute the rest of the code in java

Tags: java, android

I'm learning app development for Android and have a small problem with my code. In the google tutorial i am working with we created a coffe ordering app. I did some extra coding for my plus and minus buttons, because i wanted them to update the price while changing the amount of cups ordered. That worked great, the moment i press the button the amount of cups and the total price get updated at the same time.

Now here comes my problem. I wanted to output a string with "Total: " + totalPrice, but that doesn't work and i found out why.

```
public void addCups(View view) {
    numberOfCups = numberOfCups + 1;
    display(numberOfCups);
    displayMessage(gBetrag + endPreis);
}
```

Here are my global variables:

```
int numberOfCups = 0;
int priceOfCup = 5;
String message = "Vielen Dank!";
String gBetrag = "Gesamt: ";
String endPreis = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(numberOfCups * priceOfCup);
```

I ran the code in debugging mode and found out that the method first looks for whats in "gBetrag" and "endPreis" before it updates the "numberOfCups" variable.
The output is "Gesamt: 0.00€" because endPreis is calculated before numberOfCups gets a +1. How do get java to execute the code in the order it was written or rather read the variable after it was updated?

I can workaround this issue if add the variable to every method i want to use it in, but that just adds more code and i tought that's why you use global variables.

Comment: How you calculate `endPreis`? And where? Add it to question. Because in `addCups` method you not calculate `endPreis`, you just get it from class field.

Comment: endPreis is a global variable(added in Question) that uses the number of cups and the price per cup to calculate the total price. That total price then gets converted to €.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the `endPreis` each time a cup is added:

```
public void addCups(View view) {
    numberOfCups = numberOfCups + 1;
    calculateTotal();
    display(numberOfCups);
    displayMessage(gBetrag + endPreis);
}

private void calculateTotal() {
    endPreis = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(numberOfCups * priceOfCup);
}
```

Comment: yeah i thought about that! :D( I feel a bit of noob proud) I just thought about adding a update method, but thought it would be a bit overkill for such a simple problem.

Comment: i added the update method and now it works as i expected it to work. thx

Comment: It isn't overkill, global variables aren't functions, which is what I think you were trying to treat them as. If a variable is global it just means that its *value* can be accessed throughout the class (or other classes, if they are `public`), but that value is not recalculated every time they are accessed. That's what functions are for.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your class is written this way :

```
public class MyClass {
  int numberOfCups = 0;
  int priceOfCup = 5;
  String message = "Vielen Dank!";
  String gBetrag = "Gesamt: ";
  String endPreis = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(numberOfCups * priceOfCup);

  public void addCups(View view) {
      numberOfCups = numberOfCups + 1;
      display(numberOfCups);
      displayMessage(gBetrag + endPreis);
  }
}
```

So here is how your code will be executed :

1. `numberOfCups` is set to `0`
2. `priceOfCup` is set to `5`
3. `message` is set
4. `gBetrag` is set
5. `endPreis` is set to (`numberOfCups * priceOfCup`)
6. When you call `addCups()`, it will display `endPreis` value.

As you could see, `endPreis` value was never re-calculated ;)

Comment: but why does it do that if there is a numberOfCups+1 before the message is displayed?

Comment: `NumberFormat...` make a calculation, convert the result into a String and store this String in `endPreis`. when you make `numberOfCups + 1` you *are not* triggering `NumberFormat`, so the `endPreis` value will never change. The important point is : `endPreis` *is not* linked to `numberOfCups` at all ! It just stores the result of a multiplication already done, so it will never update itself ;)

Comment: @Redbeard As mithrop explains here, a computer will do exactly what you tell it to do and nothing more. Part of the key here is understanding the order in which your code is executed. Also, you need to understand that changing one variable doesn't automatically change other variables which were previously calculated based on that variable. You have to explicitly do these calculations in the exact order that you wish them to occur.

Comment: So using a variable doesn't update it while used. Well, it all makes sense now. Thank you guys!